# assigning values of 2d array inside a struct

Tags: c, arrays, 2d, structure

I have the following error 
expected ':', ',', ';', '}' or '**attribute**' before '=' token

```
struct arrap{
 char p[6][6] = {
    {' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' '},
    {' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' '},
    {' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' '},
    {' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' '},
    {' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' '},
    {' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' '}
    };
};
```

it seems that it doesnt work any other ways to initialize the values of the 2d array inside a structure?

Answer (score 3):

This is the correct way:

```
struct arrap {
     char p[6][6];
} a = {{{' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' '},
        {' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' '},
        {' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' '},
        {' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' '},
        {' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' '},
        {' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' '}
      }};
```

It declares the type `struct arrap` and declares an object `a` of type `struct arrap` with the initializers you wanted.

You cannot set default initializer values for a type in C but you can initialize an object at declaration time.

Comment: it answered my question but 
int main(){
 int x,i;
 struct arrayp p;
 for(i = 0;i<5;i++){
  for(x = 0; x<5;x++){
   printf("%c\n",p.p[i][x]);
  }
 }
it prints characters that is not ' ' why is it?

Comment: @PNC except that you have to use `6` instead of `5` in your loops, this looks fine to me. Remember that `' '` are white spaces. Otherwise, please show the whole program.

Answer (score 2):

You can't assign to an array inside a structure. You have to initialize it when you create an instance of the structure.

The easiest way is probably to have a constant static array, and use e.g. [`memcpy`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/memcpy) to copy it:

```
static const char p_template[6][6] = { ... };

...

struct arrap ap;
memcpy(ap.p, p_template, sizeof(p_template));
```

Answer (score 1):

Quick & Dirty:

```
struct arrap s;
memset(&s, ' ', sizeof(s.p));
```

This works as the address of the 1<sup>st</sup> member of a `struct` is guaranteed to be the same address of the `struct` itself.